# Selecting records which does not include particular value in any of the records

Tags: sql, select, hive

I am facing a difficulty in SQL. I have account no's and plans. I want to know all the people who are not enrolled in a particular plan.

```
acct  plans  
1     planA  
1     planB  
2     planA  
3     planC  
4     planD
```

I need people who have not enrolled in planA. My current query is:

```
select * from table where plans <> 'planA'
```

But I'm also getting acct 1 since the row has planB. I need acct 3,4 as output only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select * from accplans a
where a.acct not in
  (select a2.acct from accplans a2 where a2.plans = 'planA')
```

Comment: Thanks stephan..subquery will not work in hive. Only you can pass values in subquery but not a query

Comment: really? did not try out, but doku sais that `NOT IN` together with an uncorrelated subquery is allowed from hive 0.13 on. (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to use self-join. Joins are costly operations. You might try a different approach.

```
SELECT acct, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN plans='planA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS hasPlanA
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY acct
HAVING hasPlanA = 0
```

With above statement, you are actually counting how many times a customer has subscribed for planA. The `HAVING` clause filters only the results with zero planA subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Just another possible query, that builds the list of plans , a member is subscribed to and checks if planA isnt in that list -

```
with temptable as 
( 
  select acct,collect_list(plans) as plan_list
  from plantable
  group by acct
)
select * from temptable  
where array_contains(plan_list,'planA') = false;
```